# Calling Micronaut service using AJAX fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, micronaut

I have a Micronaut service that is invoked from a client using an AJAX call implemented in JQuery. The Micronaut service is shown below:

```
 @Controller("/ajaxcaller")
 public class AjaxService
{
   @Get("/printit")
   @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
   public String updateData(Session theSess)
   {
      System.out.println("Accessing from AJAX.");

      return("Successful!");
   }
}
```

The Javascript that invokes the micronaut service is below:

```
  $.ajax({
      url : '/ajaxcaller/printit',
      type: "GET",
      contentType: 'application/text',
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
         alert("Get successful! "+data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
         alert("Get failed! Error: "+jqXHR.status+", "+errorThrown);
      }
  });
```

Unfortunately, despite the fact that I am telling the server and the client to handle plain text, the AJAX call fails with the following message:

```
 Get failed! Error: 415, Unsupported Media Type
```

Have I found a bug in Micronaut's controller handlers, or am I missing something in either my client or server code? Is there some way to get this AJAX call to work?

UPDATE: following the advice provided by James in answer 1 below, the following changes were made to the code as shown below:

```
 @Controller("/ajaxcaller")
 public class AjaxService
 {
   @Get("/printit")
   @Consumes("application/text")
   public String updateData(Session theSess)
   {
      System.out.println("Accessing from AJAX.");

      return("Successful!");
   }
}
```

I am still getting the 415 failure message when I attempt to use the service.

Because I have created and successfully used other Get services in Micronaut before, I performed a test on this one using a different page. Basically, instead of using an ajax call to invoke the service, I used the following line in the HTML file:

```
window.location.href = '/ajaxcaller/printit';
```

Calling this causes a new page to be generated that displays the string returned by the service (which was, of course, the expected behavior). No 415 errors are generated -- even if I remove the @Consumes annotation.

Clearly, the Micronaut service is handling the AJAX invocation differently from a regular page invocation. Is there a setting on the AJAX side that I am missing, or is there a bug in Micronaut that is preventing successful AJAX invocations?

Comment: it seems you are not passing any data in your Ajax ?? In this case, it will surely throw that error cause there is no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Rohit Mittal's comment identified the problem. By removing the contentType setting from the AJAX call, I was able to eliminate the 415 failures.

I did some further experimentation, and discovered that with AJAX calls the content type should be specified accurately both at the client and the server. If, however, you are just doing a GET using AJAX without passing anything to the service, then do not set a content type, because that will cause 415 failures whether you add a @Consumes annotation to the service or not.

If you are not using AJAX, these considerations apparently become irrelevant. Micronaut services work under these conditions when AJAX calls fail.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you are sending a media type that is unsupported.

`@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)` tells Micronaut what content type will be produced. You haven't specified anything about the content type that can be *consumed*, so it defaults to `application/json`.

Adding `@Consumes("application/text")` will tell Micronaut the content type you are going to be consuming, which is based on your ajax call you provided.

Comment: James: Adding the @Consumes annotation did not work. I am still getting the 415 error. The change in code is added in the above edit.